# Probability question involving guessing the outcome 5 coin tossed together

Tags: probability

5 coin are tossed together, in which the outcome is either heads or tails. what is the probability of guessing the outcome of  5 coins correctly, in another separate event what is the probability of guessing 4 coins correctly, and lastly in another separate event what is the probability of guessing 3 coins correctly

Comment: do you distinguish the coins? you don't mention explicitely but I assume you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To guess a coin correcly, the probability is $\tfrac{1}{2}$. To guess a coin wrongly, the probability is again $\tfrac{1}{2}$.

We are assuming now you distinguish the coins, otherwise it's a very different problem.

So for the three questions, you have to count how many ways you can get 5, 4, or 3 coins right. We get the probabilities $p_5, p_4, p_3$:
$$ p_5 = \frac{1}{2^5}$$
$$ p_4 = {{5}\choose{4}} \frac{1}{2^5} = \frac{5}{2^5}$$
$$ p_3 = {{5}\choose{3}} \frac{1}{2^5} = \frac{10}{2^5}$$
Note that $p_2=p_3, p_1=p_4$ and $p_0=p_5$.

Answer (score 0):

You toss 5 coins, and each coin is either heads or tails. SO you can guess the outcome of all five coins correctly with a probability $p_5 = \frac {1}{2^5}$ (As when you toss the first one it has 2 outcomes, the second one has 2 outcomes etc... So you end up with $2*2*2*2*2$ possibilities)

Comment: and if you still toss 5 coins, you can guess the outcome of 4 of them with a probability $p_4 = \frac {1}{2^4}$